# Java/Hibernate - Add extra fields into an array table?

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, collections

Is it possible to add a boolean field into an array table in hibernate? I know this goes against the theoretical structure of an array, but maybe there's another collection type usable with hibernate that can do this?

i.e. (for illustration purposes)

```
idPerson      idAddress    indx      currentlyResident
    2             32        0               1

where idPerson is key
indx is index
idAddress is many-to-many
```

Thanks!

edit: This boolean value needs to be saved as part of the cross-reference table

Hibernate Mapping is very standard, just need to get an extra property in there!

```
<array name="addresses" table="personAddressCrossReference" cascade="all">
   <key column="idPerson" />
   <index column="indx" />
   <many-to-many column="idAddress" class="etc." />
</array>
```

Comment: Please show your hibernate-mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Add a attribute to your class and set it transient:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property

you have to calculate and set the value yourself. You may use the @PostConstruct annotation.

Comment: Does making it transient not mean that it will only be valid for the lifetime of the instance? This value needs to be saved as part of the cross-reference table. Also, in trying to think of where the getter and setter should be placed, would it be in the Person or Address object?

Comment: Ohh, then I misunderstood your question.